# Primary monitor audio device not available on Nvidia GPU with MST

Tags: nvidia, sound, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors daisy-chained on display port connected to my Nvidia 4070 using MST. I have speakers connected to the audio out on my primary monitor (Dell U2419HC), but the sound settings only shows the motherboard Line Out or the secondary display when I use MST. If I disable MST then it outputs through the primary monitor but I lose the second monitor. I'm on driver version 525.105.17. The setup worked fine on my previous AMD 5500XT and works fine on Windows on the same machine, and for my work laptop which I also use on the same monitors.

I can't find any options for audio in the Nvidia settings. I'd be happy if it would use the primary monitor and not offer audio from the secondary. I can only find older posts saying MST is not well supported on Nvidia drivers, and an article from 2019 saying audio over MST is now supported.

Comment: I would make the educated guess Ubuntu, the unknow version you are running can not understand 2 monitors joined like that.